# No Camera Rendering in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webrtc, augmented-reality

I am trying to send a AR camera stream to a web browser using **Unity.Webrtc**. First I initiate the signaling between the unity peer and the browser peer and I try to capture the ar camera of the **ARFoundtion** library using the following code:

```
var track = arCamera.CaptureStreamTrack(1280, 720, 0);
localConnection.AddTrack(track);
```

Where localConnection is an **RTCPeerConnection**
and in the browser I recieve the following mediastream Object:

```
[0:MediaStream{id : "b0ca5dca-0fd0-4bf6-81d4-1bd60945edc5" , active : true , onactive: null , onaddtrack: null}]
```

Then after adding this MediaStream to srcObj of video element it does not work and I get No Camera Rendering error in unity

[image: Unity Scene]

Comment: In the screenshot it looks like you are rendering to a render texture, so the game view shows "No Camera Rendering". This is the expected behavior, I would say.

Comment: What Juri is saying is: In your `AR Camera` you have a `RenderTexture` assigned to `Camera`->`Target Texture`. As soon as this is the case this camera now only renders into the assigned `RenderTexture` and produces no output to the screen anymore